# How to sign up in windows store unab

Tags: store

I had signed up and set up a family Microsoft group but still unable to get apps from the microsoft windows store I had also tried too many times about this problem but nothing works in fact I had also asked or submitted  about my this problem but nothing works at all

Comment: Mhat xind of Microsoft Family Group? What errors are you getting? Are you under 18? I had same issues with this too when I was under 18.

Comment: What device are you using? Is it running Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: No I am not under 18.....and using window 10 mobile

Comment: You may have to change the date/time of your phone, switch it to manual rather than automatic and see if that helps